# Speeding up sorting with filtering by joined column

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have the following database schema which is the base layer of an NFT marketplace I'm working on:

```sql
CREATE TABLE collections (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Implicit collection_id -> collections fk
CREATE TABLE tokens (
  contract BYTEA NOT NULL,
  token_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  collection_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(contract, token_id)
);

CREATE INDEX tokens_collection_id_contract_token_index
  ON tokens (collection_id, contract, token_id);

-- Implicit collection_id -> collections fk
CREATE TABLE attribute_keys (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  collection_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  key TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Implicit attribute_key_id -> attribute_keys fk
CREATE TABLE attributes (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  attribute_key_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  value TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Implicit contract, token_id -> tokens fk
-- collection_id, key, value denormalized from the other attribute tables
CREATE TABLE token_attributes (
  attribute_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  contract BYTEA NOT NULL,
  token_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  collection_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  key TEXT NOT NULL,
  value TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(contract, token_id, attribute_id)
);

CREATE INDEX token_attributes_collection_id_key_value_contract_token_id_index
  ON token_attributes (collection_id, key, value, contract, token_id);

-- Implicit address, token_id -> tokens fk
CREATE TABLE nft_transfer_events (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  block INT NOT NULL,
  address BYTEA NOT NULL,
  token_id NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX nft_transfer_events_contract_token_id_block_index
  ON nft_transfer_events (address, token_id, block DESC);
```

Two of the main use-cases we have are getting the latest events for a collection and getting the latest events for all tokens within a collection that match the given attribute filter. Unfortunately, both of these queries are quite inefficient since it involves filtering by columns in joined tables.

Here's the query to filter transfer events to a particular collection:

```sql
# explain analyze select * from nft_transfer_events nte join tokens t on nte.address = t.contract and nte.token_id = t.token_id where t.collection_id = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d' order by block desc limit 20;

                                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=43312.03..43314.36 rows=20 width=1071) (actual time=52990.391..53040.926 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=43312.03..180799.76 rows=1178384 width=1071) (actual time=52990.388..53040.919 rows=20 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=42312.00..43784.98 rows=589192 width=1071) (actual time=52789.050..52789.056 rows=16 loops=3)
               Sort Key: nte.block DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 49kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 47kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 43kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.26..26633.82 rows=589192 width=1071) (actual time=0.316..52759.414 rows=20586 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Index Scan using tokens_collection_id_contract_token_id_index on tokens t  (cost=0.69..12539.19 rows=5065 width=907) (actual time=0.137..343.623 rows=3333 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: (collection_id = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d'::text)
                     ->  Index Scan using nft_transfer_events_address_token_id_block_index on nft_transfer_events nte  (cost=0.57..2.77 rows=1 width=164) (actual time=3.580..15.719 rows=6 loops=10000)
                           Index Cond: ((address = t.contract) AND (token_id = t.token_id))
 Planning Time: 12.243 ms
 Execution Time: 53041.192 ms
(16 rows)
```

And here's the query to filter transfer events to tokens in a collection having a particular attribute (this can get even messier when I need to filter by multiple attributes - which would involve multiple joins on the `token_attributes` table):

```sql
# explain analyze select * from nft_transfer_events nte join token_attributes ta on nte.address = ta.contract and nte.token_id = ta.token_id where ta.collection_id = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d' and ta.key = 'Fur' and ta.value = 'Tan' order by block desc limit 20;

                                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=5.72..5.73 rows=1 width=258) (actual time=18173.114..18173.122 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=5.72..5.73 rows=1 width=258) (actual time=18173.112..18173.117 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: nte.block DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 45kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.26..5.71 rows=1 width=258) (actual time=0.164..18166.759 rows=3974 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using token_attributes_collection_id_key_value_contract_token_id_index on token_attributes ta  (cost=0.69..2.91 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.098..524.036 rows=626 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((collection_id = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d'::text) AND (key = 'Fur'::text) AND (value = 'Tan'::text))
               ->  Index Scan using nft_transfer_events_address_token_id_block_index on nft_transfer_events nte  (cost=0.57..2.79 rows=1 width=164) (actual time=6.216..28.175 rows=6 loops=626)
                     Index Cond: ((address = ta.contract) AND (token_id = ta.token_id))
 Planning Time: 61.328 ms
 Execution Time: 18173.249 ms
```

What I'm looking for is ways to speed up these two particular queries. I would be open to even redesign the schema to better fit these two use-cases.

In case it might be relevant, the table sizes are as follows:

- nft_transfer_events: ~100 million rows
- tokens: ~50 million rows
- token_attributes: ~200 million rows

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the title you mention speeding up sorting, but the sort itself takes a trivial amount of time.  It is waiting for the inputs to the sort that take all the time.  And most of that is consumed at the bottom of the nested loop:

```
->  Index Scan using nft_transfer_events_address_token_id_block_index on nft_transfer_events nte  (cost=0.57..2.77 rows=1 width=164) (actual time=3.580..15.719 rows=6 loops=10000)
      Index Cond: ((address = t.contract) AND (token_id = t.token_id))
```

Multiplying loops by actual time (per loop) gets 157 seconds.  Since it is happening over 3 processes in parallel, you can divide by 3 to see that this one thing is almost the entire amount of time spent on the query.

The index is well-suited to the way is is being used, so I have to assume it is bottlenecked by IO.  For each loop it has to jump to a random index leaf page to find the indexed data, then to 6 random table pages to get the remaining data.  The only data in the table which is not in the index is nft_transfer_events.id.  So if you either added "id" to the end of indexed columns in that index (by recreating the index), or refrained from selecting nft_transfer_events.id in the first place (by replacing `*` with just the list of columns you need) you should be able to get an index-only scan, which should be like 7 times faster if the table is well vacuumed.

If you can't do that because there are more column in the table you need that you didn't tell us about, one way speed it up would be to CLUSTER  nft_transfer_events on the index.  That way the reads into the table would not be random, but would hit the same block over and over because related nft would be next to each other.  The problem here is that CLUSTER takes a strong lock on the table, and has to be repeated occasionally as it only clusters existing data not future data.

Or, you could get faster storage so reading random pages doesn't take as long.

A radically different approach would be try to get a plan that reads the data already in order, filtering out the rows it needs to, and stopping once it finds 20 which pass the filter.  It is hard to say if this would be better or not, because I cannot predict how many of the most recent blocks belong to the collection (or other criteria) you care about.  To do this, you would need an index on  nft_transfer_events that starts with "block", so that can be read in block order.  (You might want to add the other columns to end of that index so it can get an index-only scan on it).  But then you would need to be able to efficiently determine if an identified token met your other criteria, but it looks like you already have a good index to do that.